# Toggle image fails to toggle and flashes the whole page on clicking with Electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

With Electron, I'm trying to create a toggle image button to switch between two images on clicking

- `images/img1.png`
- `images/img2.png`

However, with the following code, the image simply flashes on clicking without switching.

What's wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bookmarker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<!-- <body>
    <h1>Hello from Electron</h1>
</body>
<p>
    <button class="alert">Current Directory</button>
</p> -->
<h1>Bookmarker</h1>
<div class="error-message"></div>
<section class="add-new-link">
    <form class="new-link-form">
        <input type="image" id="img-1" class="img-btn" src="images/img1.png" onclick="Switch(this);" width=4% height=4%>
        <input type="url" class="new-link-url" placeholder="URL" size="100" required>
        <input type="submit" class="new-link-submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</section>
<section class="links"></section>
<section class="controls">
    <button class="clear-storage">Clear Storage</button>
</section>
<script>
    require('./renderer');
</script>

</html>
```

Then the click event handler in `renderer.js`

```js
const { shell } = require('electron');


function Switch(img) {
    // img.src = img.src == "images/img1.png" ? "images/img2.png" : "images/img1.png";
    if (img.src != "images/img1.png") {
        img.src = "images/img1.png"
    } else {
        img.src = "images/img2.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when you click on your "input image" the view will refresh.
If you put your image in an img tag this should fix the problem.

```
<form class="new-link-form">
    <div>
        <img id="img-1" src="images/img1.png" onclick="Switch(this)" class="img- 
        btn" width=4% height=4%>
    </div>
    <input type="url" class="new-link-url" placeholder="URL" size="100" required>
    <input type="submit" class="new-link-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Your script with conditional (ternary) operator should work normally

```
function Switch(img) {
    img.src = img.src == "images/img1.png" ? "images/img2.png" : "images/img1.png"
}
```

Another possibility is to use lastIndexOf () like this

**js**

```
 function switchImg2(img) {
        let index = img.src.lastIndexOf("/")
        let imgName = img.src.substring(index)
        console.log(imgName) // /450.jpg
        img.src = imgName == "/450.jpg" ? "./src/img/460.jpg" : 
 "./src/img/450.jpg";
    }
```

**html**

```
 <div>
     <img src="./src/img/450.jpg" alt=""  onclick="switchImg2(this)">
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, <img> fixes the flash, but the switch still doesn't happen. The onclick event handler was called, but the ternary statement results in no change in the image.

Comment: As you can see on my codepen [link](https://codepen.io/Ljosalfheim/pen/eYNYBzg) it works. maybe you have a problem with the path of your images?

Comment: Your link works, but it uses weblinks to images instead of local image files. I noticed that if I copy the exact same code but using local image files with relative paths like `images/file.png`, then it won't work.

Comment: OK, I narrowed down the problem: The function only works with absolute image paths if they are local files. But giving absolute paths is impractical. I hope there is a way to allow for relative paths like in the question.

Comment: I just tested the code in my ide and when I run it, in my case too the function only works with absolute image paths

Answer (score 0):

@Cyril Wallis-Davy solved the flash problem.

The other half of the problem was that the toggle simply doesn't work.

To make the switch happen, we have to use absolute paths for images in the function. A practical way is to get the parent folder of current script and construct the full paths to the images.

```js
// renderer.js

const { shell } = require('electron');

function Switch(img) {
    let scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    let srcPath = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
    let dirPath = srcPath.match(/(.*)[\/\\]/)[1]||'';

    img.src = img.src == dirPath+"/images/img1.png" ? dirPath+"/images/img2.png" : dirPath+"/images/img1.png"
}
```

Comment: I edited my post with a solution that uses lastIndexOf () instead of a regex